# Is the ring of continous real-valued functions on [0, 1] commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am currently reading Undergraduate Algebra (S.Lang) and i stuck into a problem ) in the book it is given as an example ) from which i can not go further.
"Let R be the ring of continous real-valued functions on the interval [0, 1]. Let J be the subset of functions $f$ such that $f(\frac{1}{2})=0.$ Then J is an ideal (two-sided since R is commutative)."

1. How can R be commutative ? I presume that the operation of multiplication in the ring R is thought to be the composition of mappings. Given $f\in J$ and $g\in R$, one can not avoid the general relation $fg\neq gf$ for mappings.
2. Even in the case R were commutative, is J well defined ? I mean the following: let $f\in J$ and $g\in R$. By the definition of an ideal, $fg\in J, \forall g\in R$. But the function $g$ must not take the value $\frac{1}{2}$ on the interval [0, 1].

I will appreciate any comment. Thanks.

Comment: The multiplication law is just multiplication, $f\times g(x)=f(x)\times g(x)$.  composition doesn;t even make sense.

Comment: @lulu consider making that an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here, the ring operations are just inherited from the ring operations on $\mathbb R$.  Thus, if $f,g\in R$ we have $$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)\quad \&\quad (f\times g)(x)=f(x)\times g(x)$$

With these definitions, I think it is clear that $J$ is indeed an ideal.

It may be worth remarking that composition isn't even defined, as the range of one function need not be included in the domain of another.